# How can I install cisco packet tracer on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: server, software-installation, 19.10

When I'm trying to install packet tracer on Ubuntu 19.10 I have this problem: ./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Your title & description says 19.10, but then you've tagged 12.04 & 14.04? and also server? & xubuntu? (a desktop release and not server).  Why tag EOL releases?  and contradictory tags? so please confirm your release.   `libpng12` is available for older releases (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libpng12 https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng12-0)

Answer (score 0):

Download deb package of libpng12, open it using archive manager, find libpng12.so.0 and libpng12.so.0.54.0 (or equivalent), then  extract it to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.